# Search the string in c# using LINQ

Tags: c#

I have a Dictionary> in c#

```
    Dictionary<string,List<string>> l_dictRawData;
```

which contains the values are :

```
                KEYS                 VALUES
   l_dictRawData["TamilNadu"] => VALUE[0] = "Chennai" VALUE[1] = "Madurai"
   l_dictRawData["Andhra"] = > VALUE[0] = "Hyderabad" VALUE[1] = "Secundarabad"
   l_dictRawData["Karnataka"] = > VALUE[0] = "mysore" VALUE[1] = "Bangalore"
```

Then i have the InputList

```
  List<string> l_lstInput = new List<string>();
```

Which contains the data are :

```
  l_lstInput[0] = "Hyderabad"
  l_lstInput[1] = "Secundarabad"
```

The result will be the (i.e) if the dictionary l_dictRawData contains both
"Hyderabad" and "Secundarabad" ,then select the KEy value .

```
 string l_strOutPut = "Andhra";
```

Here is my code :

```
                            var Query = from l_strData in l_dictRawData
                            from l_strItem in l_lstInput
                            where l_strData .Value.Contains(l_strItem )
                            select new
                            {
                                CityName = l_strItem,
                                StateName = l_strData.Key
                            };
```

How can i get the ouput using LINQ in c#

If u have any queries plz let me know

Comment: Plz send the codz? No thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, a `Dictionary` with what you're looking for in the *value* isn't really an appropriate datastructure for this, but you can do:

```
var query = from pair in l_dictRawData
            where pair.Value.SequenceEquals(l_lstInput)
            select pair.Key;
```

That will give *all* the keys matching the given value. You can then use one of `query.First()`, `query.FirstOrDefault()`, `query.Single()` or `query.SingleOrDefault()` to get a single result, depending on your requirements.

Comment: skeet : Can u tell me which data structure is suitable for the above question

Comment: @user374191: If you're trying to look up *from* the pair of values, I'd suggest a `Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, string>` so that your pair of values is the key in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested but you should find that this works or else is close enough to amend to your needs:

```
var matches = (
from kvPair in l_dictRawData
where l_lstInput.Contains(kvPair.Value)
where l_lstInput.Contains(kvPair.Key)
select new {
MatchedVal = kvPair.Value
}
).ToList();
```

This will return all the key values from the dictionary where the dictionary item contains both of the elements present in you l_lstInput collection.

Comment: @user374191: I've provided a solution to your original question and then you've subsequently updated your question. That's pretty frustrating, do I have to keep updating my answer because you've not taken the time to explain your question correctly each time?

Answer (score 0):

For contains option to work as like we should also consider the case of the string 
for e.g. look below

```
searchUserName = searchUserName.ToLower();
            var results = orgUserEmailSettingsTOList.Where(c => c.UserDisplayName.ToLower().Contains("" + searchUserName + "")).ToList();

        return results;
```